# Aggregate rows based on the value of the next row

Tags: r, dataframe, aggregate

Suppose I have the following dataframe:

```
Category = c("blue", "red",  "red", "blue", "blue", "blue", "red", "red", "red","blue", "red", "red","blue","blue","red","blue","red")
Purchase  = c(0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,1,0,1)
Number  = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2)
Id = c("a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","a","b","b","b","b","b","b","b","b")
Country = c("NL","BE","BE","UK","UK","NL","UK","UK","UK","BE","NL","NL","BE","UK","UK","BE","NL")

df = data.frame(Id, Number,Category, Purchase, Country)
    > df
   Id Number Category Purchase Country
1   a      1     blue        0      NL
2   a      1      red        1      BE
3   a      1      red        1      BE
4   a      1     blue        0      UK
5   a      2     blue        0      UK
6   a      2     blue        0      NL
7   a      2      red        1      UK
8   a      2      red        1      UK
9   a      2      red        1      UK
10  b      1     blue        0      BE
11  b      1      red        1      NL
12  b      2      red        1      NL
13  b      2     blue        0      BE
14  b      2     blue        0      UK
15  b      2      red        1      UK
16  b      2     blue        0      BE
17  b      2      red        1      NL
```

I would like to aggregate the rows where red is followed by red, grouped by the Id and the Number, such that the Purchases of these rows are summarized. Thus, my desired output would be:

```
    > desired
   Id Number Category Purchase Country
1   a      1     blue        0      NL
2   a      1      red        2      BE
3   a      1     blue        0      UK
4   a      2     blue        0      UK
5   a      2     blue        0      NL
6   a      2      red        3      UK
7   b      1     blue        0      BE
8   b      1      red        1      NL
9   b      2      red        1      NL
10  b      2     blue        0      BE
11  b      2     blue        0      UK
12  b      2      red        1      UK
13  b      2     blue        0      BE
14  b      2      red        1      NL
```

Hence, the order in which the categories occur should be maintained and only the ones with category "red" should be aggregated. Also, in my real dataframe I have several columns such as the Country column, which I would like to be present in the output as well, but I don't want to manually define all those columns. I have tried to use the `aggregate` function or `ddply`, but I still haven't sorted it out.

Can someone help me with this aggregation problem where the order of the rows is taken into account?

Comment: Variant of @jogo's deleted answer: `library(data.table); setDT(df)[, .(Purchase = if (Category=="red") sum(Purchase) else Purchase), by=.(Id, Number, Category, rleid(Id, Number, Category))]`

Answer (score 3):

Here is one option with `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df)`), grouped by the run-length-id of logical column (`Category == "red"`), along with 'Id', 'Number' and 'Category', `if` the number of elements are greater than 1 and `all` the elements in 'Category' are 'red', then get the `sum` of 'Purchase' or `else` return 'Purchase'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, .(Purchase = if(.N > 1 & all("red" %in% Category)) sum(Purchase) 
            else Purchase), by = .(grp = rleid(Category == "red"), Id, Number, Category)
          ][, grp := NULL][]
#    Id Number Category Purchase
# 1:  a      1     blue        0
# 2:  a      1      red        2
# 3:  a      1     blue        0
# 4:  a      2     blue        0
# 5:  a      2     blue        0
# 6:  a      2      red        3
# 7:  b      1     blue        0
# 8:  b      1      red        1
# 9:  b      2      red        1
#10:  b      2     blue        0
#11:  b      2     blue        0
#12:  b      2      red        1
#13:  b      2     blue        0
#14:  b      2      red        1
```

Comment: The `all` around `x %in% y`  is unnecessary since `x` has length one.

Comment: @Frank You are right.  I put that as a general case in case the OP wants to extend to more than one 'Category'

Comment: @akrun thank you, this really helps! In my real dataframe I have more columns than those in my example, how should I adjust your answer in order to make sure those are present in the output, without having to manually type in all those columns ?

Comment: @MC09  It is not clear when you say that there are more columns.   Did you meant there are pairs of 'Purchase'/'Category' columns ?

Comment: @akrun I will adjust my question such that it becomes clear what I was trying to say.

Answer (score 2):

```
df$temp = with(data = rle(as.character(df$Category)),
     cumsum(unlist(sapply(seq_along(values), function(i){
         if(values[i] == "red"){
             c(1, rep(0, lengths[i]-1))
         }else{
             rep(1, lengths[i])
         }}))))
aggregate(Purchase~., df, sum)
#   Id Number Category temp Purchase
#1   a      1     blue    1        0
#2   a      1      red    2        2
#3   a      1     blue    3        0
#4   a      2     blue    4        0
#5   a      2     blue    5        0
#6   a      2      red    6        3
#7   b      1     blue    7        0
#8   b      1      red    8        1
#9   b      2      red    8        1
#10  b      2     blue    9        0
#11  b      2     blue   10        0
#12  b      2      red   11        1
#13  b      2     blue   12        0
#14  b      2      red   13        1
```

Answer (score 1):

here's a way using `dpyr`.

First I build a subgroup incrementing when color changes in groups, along with `Id` and `Number` it defines sub `data.frames`.

Then I use `do` on sub `data.frames` that contain `red` to aggregate Purchases.

Then I clean the groups and extra column.

```
df %>%
  group_by(Id,Number,subgroup = cumsum(c(TRUE,head(Category,-1) != tail(Category,-1)))) %>%
  do({if(.$Category[1] == "red") aggregate(Purchase ~ .,.,sum) else .}) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-subgroup) 

# # A tibble: 14 x 4
#        Id Number Category Purchase
#    <fctr>  <dbl>   <fctr>    <dbl>
#  1      a      1     blue        0
#  2      a      1      red        2
#  3      a      1     blue        0
#  4      a      2     blue        0
#  5      a      2     blue        0
#  6      a      2      red        3
#  7      b      1     blue        0
#  8      b      1      red        1
#  9      b      2      red        1
# 10      b      2     blue        0
# 11      b      2     blue        0
# 12      b      2      red        1
# 13      b      2     blue        0
# 14      b      2      red        1
```